# AMPScript variables from file

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, email, ampscript, dynamic

I will need a few AMPScript variables in a template. The same variables will be used in several templates thought I would write a file that populates them and use some include function the way one does in html. Now I wonder if:

1. It's possible at all
2. The variables defined in the script will be accessible to other content elements in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do that.

I'm working on an email right now that initializes and sets base AMPScript variables in the template and then overrides the values in the email.

**Template**

```
%%[
var @bodyStyle, @footerColor
set @bodyStyle = "style='background-color:green'"
set @footerColor = "#ffffff"
]%%
<custom type="content" name="init">
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body %%=v(@bodyStyle)=%%>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color:%%=v(@footerColor)=%%">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Email Init Content Area**

```
%%[
if @whatever == "whee" then
  set @bodyStyle = "style='background-color:green'"
  set @footerColor = "#666666"
endif
]%%
```

You can also dynamically retrieve a stored Content Area and reference it with the [ContentAreaByName()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/ContentAreaByName.html) function.  The Content Area can contain whatever scripting you need.

Comment: Thank you I already have the template created from a wizard and I can not modify it. I saw the ContentAreasByName in other post but I didn't know how to use it so I intuitively turned to researching server side javascript. SO can I just use %%=ContentAreaByName(@contentPath)=%% to load the content and then reference the variables? I will test